# How to write conditional autocompletion in Click CLI (Python)

Tags: python, click

Say I have an write a CLI interface with click with 2 args.

- My app named: `foo`
- First arg is: `[BAR]`
- Second arg is: `[BAZ]`
  So to run my command that is `foo [BAR] [BAZ]`. For example `foo hello friend`

However, it will have some constraint:

- if `[BAR] = hello` then `[BAZ]` should be suggested `friend`: `foo hello friend`
- else if `[BAR] = yo` then `[BAZ]` should be suggested `bro`: `foo yo bro`

I've read the [autocompletion doc of Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/shell-completion/), with input as `ctx`, `param`, `incomplete`

```py
def autocomplete_func(ctx, param, incomplete):
  ....
```

However `param` does not let me access to current state of command (e.g: last input of `[BAR]` when at `[BAZ]`)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this case. Click autocomplete function actually provides access to former argument through `ctx.params`

```py
def autocomplete_func(ctx, param, incomplete):
    # Get last argument from ctx
    bar_value = ctx.params["bar"]
    
    # Condition on last arg to complete later args
    if bar_value == "hello": # pass some condition here
       # Handle completion here
```